# Play Action Composition - hardcoding parameterized parser

Tags: scala, playframework, play-json, context-bound

I would like to create a custom action which takes away the boilerplate of writing actions like this:

```
Action[MyClass](BodyParsers.parse.json[MyClass]) { req => ...
```

However, I keep running into class definition errors. Here has been my most successful attempt:

```
class JsonAction[A: Reads] extends ActionBuilder[Request] {
  def hardcodedJson[A: Reads](action: Action[A]) = 
    Action.async(BodyParsers.parse.json[A]) { request => action(request) }

  def invokeBlock[A: Reads](request: Request[A], block: (Request[A]) => Future[Result]) = {
    block(request)
  }
  override def composeAction[A: Reads](action: Action[A]) = hardcodedJson(action)
}
```

but I get the following error: `method composeAction overrides nothing.`

If I change `composeAction[A: Reads]` to `composeAction[A]` it tells me there isn't a Json Serializer for type A.

Is there some other way to define this custom action?

Answer (score 1):

Yep, I tried to get this to work with the official `ActionBuilder`  way-of-doing-it and just could not get the types to line up.

Here's something that worked for me though:

```
object JsonActionHelper {
  def withReads[A](act: Request[A] => Future[Result])(implicit reads:Reads[A]) = 
    Action.async(BodyParsers.parse.json(reads))(act)
}
```

Usage in your controller (`FooJson` is an `object` containing an implicit `Reads[Foo]`):

```
import models.FooJson._
import JsonActionHelper._

def handleIncomingFoo(fooId:String) = withReads[Foo] { req =>
  val foo:Foo = req.body
  ...
  Ok(...)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ActionBuilder` is not generic enough for your use-case; there's nowhere for you to pass in your `Reads[T]`.

There's nothing special about `ActionBuilder` though. It's a collection of `apply` and `async` factory methods. You can define your own Action type with whatever factory methods you need:

```
object JsonAction {
  def apply[A : Reads](request: Request[A] => Result) = Action(BodyParsers.parse.json[A])(request)
}

// these are equivalent:
Action[MyClass](BodyParsers.parse.json[MyClass]) { req => ??? }
JsonAction[MyClass] { req => ??? }
```